# Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition.

Tags: calculus

Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition

$\frac{dp}{dt}=7(pt)^{1/2}, P(1)=7$

Comment: seperate the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Divide both sides by $p^{1/2}$; the equivalent equation is then

$$p^{-1/2} dp = 7 t^{1/2} dt$$

Integrate both sides:

$$2 p^{1/2} = \frac{14}{3} t^{3/2} + C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  Use the given condition at $t=1$ to solve for $C$.